# Is there a built-in PHP function that prints an array formatted with <pre> tags?

Tags: php, arrays, format, pre

Normally, I would use `print_r` function to do the task, but I still need to manually add the `<pre>` tags. I am wondering if there is a function in PHP that can do it automatically, something like `print_pre($array)`.

Comment: Not really, but you can create one. [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) can either dump directly to the screen or return a string, so you can append the tags yourself.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous, you might want to look into using something like Symfony's [VarDumper component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html). It'll provide you with a **lot** more useful output than a simple `print_r` will.

Answer (score 1):

[print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) has a second param, if true it returns the value.

`echo '<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>';`

Answer (score 0):

Thers's no such function for this task instead you can use

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

To make it as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, but if you would like to use advanced debug tool, you can install xdebug and it can be automatically format var_dump.

You can find more information about xdebug here: https://xdebug.org/